# How to replace the existing svn comment template with the new one

Tags: svn

In my company, developers may use tortoise svn or eclipse svn or any svn client, so no matter what they use i want to enforce them to give some commit messages and jira id in it. so, i used the below  pre-commit shell script in the svn server in hooks folder and tested with tortoise, it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

```
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"
SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
CURL=/usr/bin/curl
JIRAURL=http://our.jira.url:8080/rest/api/latest/issue
# Make sure that the log message contains some text.
LOGMSG=$($SVNLOOK log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS")
echo ${LOGMSG} | grep "[a-zA-Z0-9]" > /dev/null || exit 1
check that log message starts with a JIRA ticket
should have format 'FOO-123: my commit message' or 'FOO-123 my commit      message'
JIRAID=$(expr "${LOGMSG}" : '^\([A-Z]*-[0-9]*\)[: ].*')
 if [[ "$JIRAID" == "" ]]
then
echo "No JIRA id found in log message \"${LOGMSG}\"" >&2
echo "Please use log message of the form \"JIRA-ID: My message\"" >&2
exit 1
fi
JIRAISSUE=$(${CURL} ${JIRAURL}/${JIRAID})
if [[ "${JIRAISSUE}" =~ "Issue Does Not Exist" ]]
then
echo "The JIRA id ${JIRAID} was not found" >&2
echo "Please use log message of the form \"JIRA-ID: My message\"" >&2
exit 1
fi
```

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212640/can-we-change-the-default-svn-commit-template-using-svn-hooks

Comment: some one please help me

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple pre-commit hook that only allow commit with comments.

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
$SVNLOOK log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | \
grep "[A-Z]*-[0-9]" > /dev/null

GREP_STATUS=$?
if [ $GREP_STATUS -ne 0 ]
 then
  echo "Commit denied" 1>&2
  echo "Please write a comment to do the commit like" 1>&2
  echo "JIRA-TICKET: Message" 1>&2
  echo "Eg: FOO-123: Fix login bug" 1>&2
  exit 1
fi
exit 0
```